# Put Adsense ads in specific Blogger post

Tags: blogger, google-adsense

I have a personal Blogger blog, that doesn't get much traffic. There is however one post, that gets unusually many random hits from search engine (the picture inside of the post must have been indexed high).

I don't want to have too many ads on my blog, but I want to put an ad on the bottom of this specific post. However, it seems that Blogger doesn't allow to insert `<script>` tags inside of post.

Is there another way to put Adsense ad under only one specific post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can insert ads into individual posts:  the trick is to turn on show break-characters instead of blank lines (I tried to spell this out here, but the HTML got interpreted!)  in the post options **before** putting the code into the HTML tab of the post-editor.

Ref:   http://blogger-hints-and-tips.blogspot.com/2009/12/putting-google-adsense-advertisements.html

Comment: Works like charm. Although I couldn't find this line break option in new interface. I had to switch to old one temporarily.

Comment: @MaryC: To prevent HTML from being interpreted in a post here, enclose it in backticks: ``